# Solidworks issue: Error message 'there has to be at least one component for a flow analysis' pops up on clicking 'check geometry'

Tags: 3d, cad, solidworks, 3d-modelling

This is so frustrating- I have a fully closed solid body that I want to do a quick flow analysis of.
I go to Tools/Flow Simulation (a Solidworks add-in)/Tools/Check Geometry.
Even Solidworks says my 'geometry' is 'one closed body'. I don't know what to do as I really have to model this, would be grateful for any help.

Here is a screenshot of the error message: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb5ro.jpg)

I've gone back to change my body and export another STL file multiple times, no changes.
When I initially import the file, it comes with some other bodies that I delete before trying the geometry analysis- this shouldn't be the issue though if Solidworks says there is only one body there?
I'm also new to Solidworks so the fix could also be simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think
you should simply create your solid model in features tab and not in surface.
hope it could be useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).